# nvm 1.1.1 error while running nvm install 6.4.0

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I am using nvm 1.1.1 and when I run `nvm install 6.4.0` I get below error

**Node.js v6.4.0 is not yet released or available.**

When I try `nvm install latest`, it installs 10.1.0.

For my project 6.4.0 is required. Any idea what can be the reason?

This is the output of nvm list available
[image]

Comment: I assume this is in windows?

Comment: Yes. Its windows.

Comment: ok.. can you add the output of `nvm list available` to your question?

Comment: Also checkout this repeated issue https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/111

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks. I had a look at the link you provided but unfortunately it doesn't help. There are others having similar issues. (See few posts towards the end). For now I have a workaround (I copied v6.4.0 folder from my colleague in to my c:\nvm folder) in place but looking for the root cause.